# BehaviorSubject: ignore last value if next() didn't triggered

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

In my application I'm using BehaviorSubject to pass data from provider to page component:

**JobsManager**

```
  private futureJobsSource = new BehaviorSubject <Array<Job>>([]);
  futureJobsUpdate = this.futureJobsSource.asObservable();
```

Place where source is updating:

```
 getFutureJobs(date: string) {
//
//
this.api.getFutureJobs(request).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'getFutureJobs: success: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      this.futureJobsSource.next(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'getFutureJobs: failure: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      this.message.showErrorAlert(err.detail);
    });
}
```

And my component, **FutureJobsPage**

```
 setSearchDate() {
    DatePicker.show(this.datePickerOptions).then((date) => {
      this.jobsManager.getFutureJobs(moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FutureJobsPage');
    this.subscription = this.jobsManager.futureJobsUpdate.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'subscribe: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      this.futureJobs = res;
    });
  }

 ionViewDidLeave() {
   console.log(this.TAG + 'ionViewDidLeave');
   this.jobsManager.futureJobsUpdate.distinctUntilChanged();
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   this.futureJobs = [];
 }
```

As I understood from my search about proper way to pass data from provider BehaviorSubject is an optimal solution but I want to omit last received value if it wasn't from next(). What is the best practice to achieve such behavior?

Comment: you mean the ignore the initialized empty value?

Comment: @suraj Hi, thank you for reply. No, in my case I receive last emitted value and I want to ignore this value or replace with default empty array until next emit.

Comment: Not really clear how this is supposed to work. *I want to omit last received value if it wasn't from next()* literally means that you need no 'default empty array' and can just use Subject instead of BehaviorSubject. If this isn't so, it seems to me that one of the statements is contradictory. A simple example isolated from Angular stuff with explained input and output would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`, subscription will start only after first emit.

**BehaviorSubject**

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a
>   notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to
>   its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will
>   immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

Hope this helps!!